# How to get to previous calandar entry's after the date has passed

Tags: iphone, calendar

When entering calandar events on my calandar I sometime need to go back and see what date I made a call or went to an event. All entry's prior to today date have disappeared. How can I get back to previous events so I can see what day they happened?

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar > Sync >

Choose a longer timescale

[image]